# Rectangular nodes in Tikz Automata has no outline

Tags: tikz-styles

Will preface by saying I'm very unfamiliar with Tikz and I just edited a template.
The template was for a state diagram when I wanted to draw Markov chains.
Now, I want square nodes instead of circles because I'm doing something different; the text need causes the circle to be way too huge. I would rather have a rectangle.

I have:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, shapes}

\being{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=6.5cm, auto]
       \node[state] (TL) {$102$ JPY/USD}; 
       \node[state, accepting] (BL) [below of=TL] {$(1+r_{USD})$ USD};
       \node[rectangle] (TR) [right of=TL] {$102$ JPY};
       \node[state] (BR) [below of=TR] {$(1+r_{JPY})$ JPY};
 
       \path[->]
        (TL) edge node {$1 \text{USD} \times 102 \text{JPY}$} (TR)
        (TL) edge node {$r_{USD}$} (BL)
        (TR) edge node {$r_{JPY}$} (BR)
        (BR) edge [bend left] node {$1 \text{USD} \times 102 \text{JPY}$} (BL)
       ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Covered Interest Rate Parity}
 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But the TR node does not have an outline around it. I tried a bunch of different keywords I found around google, but only "node" seems to work. Is there no simple keyword option that can get me a rectangle?

Comment: Please edit your post to let a complete compilable Minimal Working Example in order to get some help.

Comment: Your document example is not compilable. Position option `H` is not defined (you miss to load package `float`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "draw" to "rectangle" to the options of node:

```
...
\node[rectangle, draw] (TR) [right of=TL] {$102$ JPY};
...
```

By default tikz does not draw the nodes.

Comment: Thanks. What is the purpose of [node] that was from the template then?

Comment: @Five9, if you not explicate determine, that nodes have drawn borders, than they appear without of them. This is deliberate determined nodes features.

Answer (score 1):

I would draw your image on the following way:

- define all nodes style used in diagram
- use position syntax as defined in `position` package
- enable multi (two) line text in nodes

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata, 
                positioning, 
                quotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[low-sup]{subdepth}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      node distance = 44mm and 66mm, on grid,
state/.append style = {semithick, align=center, inner sep=1pt},
         rct/.style = {draw},
  every edge/.style = {draw, -Straight Barb, semithick},
every edge quote/.style = {auto, font=\small}
                        ]
\node[state] (TL) {102\\ JPY/USD};
\node[state, accepting] (BL) [below=of TL] {$(1+r_{\text{USD}})$\\ USD};
\node[rct]   (TR) [right=of TL] {102 JPY};
\node[state] (BR) [below=of TR] {$(1+r_{\text{JPY}})$\\ JPY};
%
\path   (TL) edge ["$1\,\text{USD} \times 102\,\text{JPY}$"] (TR)
        (TL) edge ["$r_{\text{USD}}$"] (BL)
        (TR) edge ["$r_{\text{JPY}}$"] (BR)
        (BR) edge [bend left, "$1\,\text{USD} \times 102\,\text{JPY}$"] (BL)
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Covered Interest Rate Parity}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note:*
In node style is usually defined:

- type of shape (rectangle, circle, ellipse, etc)
- shape of border (draw, thickens of lines)
- size (width, height)
- separation between text and border and border and surrounding
- etc.
- Some of this attributes have default values (as `inner sep`, `outer sep`)
- for details see *TikZ and PGF manual*, chapter *17 Nodes and Edges*